# How do I open the MongoDB out? How to make authorization only for external clients?

Tags: mongodb, port, firewall

All of you since Friday night! Help Nuba, there is a backend on Node.js that uses local MongoDB and you need to throw Mongo outside. In bindIp it already costs 0.0.0.0, but no miracle happens. Plus another question, how to make authorization only for external clients, and for local clients to leave also access without authorization?

Thank you in advance to all who will respond!

MongoDB v3.4.17

cat /etc/mongod.conf - https://gist.github.com/sergey-prosvirnin/6daef1ea44726b87d99e18dd1e6548e8

sudo netstat -tnlp - https://gist.github.com/sergey-prosvirnin/10fa693d3dbb45b2ed79094a0068e748

iptables -L - https://gist.github.com/sergey-prosvirnin/b810f0d39efac9810f8280f9739201df

P.S. I opened the database temporarily, it's test and has no valuable data.

Answer (score 0):

> how to make authorization only for external clients, and for local clients to leave also access without authorization?

Authorization is either enabled for all clients or not enabled for all clients. There is no way to specify authorization requirements based on connection source.